# How to pass multiple arguments with url (routing) in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to pass argument on route but unfortunatly i am facing error please help me thanks.

> Missing required parameters for [Route: products.detail] [URI:
> products/{slug}/{id}/details]. (View:
> /home/zubair/htdocs/wallmasterfurnishing.com/web/resources/views/wallpapers-product.blade.php)

```
let detailurl = '{{route("products.detail",[":slug",":id"])}}';
productdetail = detailurl.replace(':slug', element.slug);
productdetail = detailurl.replace(':id', element.id);   

<a href="${productdetail}">
    <h4 class="prodcardtitle">${element.code} - ${element.name}</h4>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seams like you are combining Blade template with Javascript

```
let detailurl = '{{route("products.detail",[":slug",":id"])}}';
```

`let` keywords is part of `JavaScript`

and `{{ route("products.details", [$element->slug, $element->id] }}` is only available inside of blade template

As you are inside of javascript and not in blade template you should create the url using `template literals` and replace all placeholder with the the related value like this

```
let detailurl = `/products/${element.slug}/${element.id}/details`;

`<a href="${productdetail}">
    <h4 class="prodcardtitle">${element.code} - ${element.name}</h4>
</a>`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass multiple parameter to route as an array

```
<a href="{{ route('products.detail', ['slug' => $slugVariable, 'id' => $idVariable]) }}">
    <h4 class="prodcardtitle">${element.code} - ${element.name}</h4>
</a>
```

for more info [visit](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#required-parameters)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try with route name :

```
     Route::get('products/{slug}/{id}/details','ProductController@productDetail')->name('productDetail');

    <a href="{{ route('productDetail', ['laptop-slug','2']) }}">
      <h4 class="prodcardtitle">${element.code} - ${element.name}</h4>
    </a>
```